# Deleted Question about functions and ranges

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

This morning I (and @Ralf) answered a question about functions being called for every line in a range vs. once for the whole range.

It seems to have disappeared: I assume this means it was deleted, but I do not have sufficient reputation to verify that.

I thought I put some good effort into the answer, and would like to save it–I think it could be useful to others.

1. Can anyone confirm that this question was in fact deleted?
2. If so, is it appropriate to un-delete?

   1. If not, is there any way I can salvage my answer? I would consider self-answering with it, to provide it to the community, unless there's a good reason not to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume it's [How to have vnoremap call function once](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/18937/51)? It was deleted by the question author, who are allowed to do so by the software as long as there aren't any upvoted answers.

People sometimes do this once they figured out the answer and no longer think their question is useful. But providing answers that are useful to others too is an important part of the site, so I've undeleted the question again.

The author of the question can raise a custom mod flag requestion the question to be dissociated from their account if they don't want the question to appear on their account for some reason.